# How do I make my discord bot show its prefix when I mention it (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to be able to type "@Hu Tao bot prefix" and the bot will respond with what the current prefix is, for some reason it is not working, and it also shows no error message, my current prefix is:
`client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-')`

Comment: "for some reason it is not working" is not helpful to us at all, provide the code you tried so we can help you with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `message.mentions` in a event:-

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if client.user in message.mentions:
    await message.channel.send("You can type `tnj.help` for help")
  await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: thank you it works but, when i type some words then with mentioning @(the bot) it will send the prefix too. How do i make the bot will only send the prefix when the chat i sent only the mention

Comment: You can just type whatever you want to send in the ```await message.channel.send("anything you want to write")``` line